# Checkbox insert in mysql and check if checked

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

After i searched for this solution on this site, nothing i found. Here is basic php code, just for testing.

**index.php**

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk" value="1" />
<button type="button" name="" id="submit">TEST</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#submit').click(function(){  
           var check = $('#chk').val();  

                $.ajax({  
                     url:"qry.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data: {check:check},  
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          //alert(data);  
                          window.location.reload();

                     }
                });   

      });   
 });  
 </script>
```

**qry.php**

```
<?php  

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "check";

// Create connection
$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
} 

if($_REQUEST['chk'] == true){
    $stok = '1';
}
elseif ($_REQUEST['chk'] == false) {
    $stok = '0';
}
      $query = "INSERT INTO test(checked) VALUES('$stok')";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
        if ($result === TRUE) {
            echo "Zahtev je uspešno poslat!";

        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $connect->error;
        }   

 ?>
```

How to set checkbox checked true or false into mysql and then echo if in html? It's always set to 0 in mysql boolen.

```
<input type="hidden" name="chk" id="chk" value="1" <?php if ($checked == '1') {echo 'checked';} else {} ?>/>
```

I tried everything from this site and nothing works.

Comment: You want to add the check box value to the database and then echo it on to a `HTML` later is this what you want to do ?

Comment: you can use enum in mysql set 'true','false' for checkbox field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `Jquery`. This will get rid of the always value 1 problem you're having. What this code does is when you click on the "submit" button it check the status of your check box. If the check box is checked then the code will take the checked check box value and send that in the ajax function if it's not checked then the value 0 get assigned and that will be sent using the `ajax`.

Doing this will reduce the work has to be done by the back end `PHP`. I also made some changes to your `PHP` code as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
    if ($("#chk").is(":checked")) {
    var chk = $('#chk').val();
    }else{
     chk = 0;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "qry.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          check: chk
        },
        success: function(data) {
          //alert(data);  
          window.location.reload();

        }
      });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk" value="1" />
<button type="button" name="" id="submit">TEST</button>
```

You will see that the way I'm inserting the data is a bit different from the way you have done. I'm using `mysqli_` prepared statements which makes SQL injection a hard to do.

```
$query = $connect -> prepare("INSERT INTO test(checked) VALUES (?)";  
      $query -> bind_param("i", $_REQUEST['check']);
        if ($query -> execute()) {
            echo "Zahtev je uspešno poslat!";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $connect->error;
        }
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sadaruwan12/chz95x8m/) if you want to test it.

Comment: On click nothing happens, query is not submited

Comment: Are you getting any errors? and did you check the developer tools network tab in your browser to see if the query is getting submitted.

Comment: I dont get any errors, just my db does not get filled with some values or ajax realod window does not work. https://i.imgur.com/xOtyQ9u.png

Comment: if you're using a local test server change the method to "GET" and try. change `method: "POST"` to `method: "GET"`.

Comment: In network tab i got `qry.php?check=0` for unchecked and `qry.php?check=1` for checked but still nothing insertet in mysql

Comment: Did you change the `method` to `GET`?

Comment: Oh man, it works. My bad, i didnt put password for mysql database connection. Haha. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You write the value into `check`, but read it back from `$_REQUEST['chk']`. That won't work. Change that to `$_REQUEST['check']`.

You are using `val()` to get the state of the checkbox, you should use `checked`.

Also, you are possibly open to SQL injection, start using prepared statements.

Comment: I made a mistake by that, but when i changed to `$_REQUEST['check']` now it's always value 1, checked or unchecked

Comment: It should be because you're just checking the value regardless of the status of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Add another line while sending the AJAX request.

While sending the value of checkbox, send `1` or `0`.

It will reduce our work at PHP end.

So, the code should be:

```
var check = $('#chk').is(":checked");  
check = (check) ? 1 : 0;
```

Final code should be:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk" value="1" />
<button type="button" name="" id="submit">TEST</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
$('#submit').click(function(){  
 var check = $('#chk').val();  
 check = (check) ? 1 : 0;
 $.ajax({  
  url:"qry.php",  
  method:"POST",  
  data: {check:check},  
  success:function(data) {  
   //alert(data);  
   window.location.reload();
  }
 });
});   
});
</script>
```

And PHP:

```
<?php  
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "check";
// Create connection
$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($connect->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
} 
$stok = $_REQUEST['chk'];
$query = "INSERT INTO test(checked) VALUES('$stok')";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
if ($result === TRUE) {
 echo "Zahtev je uspešno poslat!";
}
else {
 echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $connect->error;
}
?>
```

Comment: Its working at my end. Please try to implement the whole code.

Comment: In your final code should be this right `var check = ('#chk').is(":checked");  check = (check) ? 1 : 0;` not this `var check =  ('#chk').val();  check = (check) ? 1 : 0;`.

Comment: I dont know what's wrong, nothing is working. Or the value is 0 or query does not even submit with `var check = ('#chk').is(":checked"); check = (check) ? 1 : 0;`